# How can i change the encoding of imagefttext() result in php gd library?

Tags: php, encoding, arabic

I'm trying to change the encoding of my imagefttext() result.
My idea is to print some text in "Arabic" language onto a specified image , but the result appear in strange 
form.
I used this code, but it is work correctly just with English string  :

`mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8'); 
 
$im =imagecreatefromjpeg('x.jpg');

$textcolor=imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

imagefttext($im, 18, 0, 10, 20,$textcolor,"Fonts/tahoma.ttf","مسعود أوزبل");

imagejpeg($im,"mozil.jpg",100);

imagedestroy($im);`

Can i have any solution for this problem ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Arabic characters can not be treated as an array**. Also `imagefttext()` **does not support RTL languages like Arabic out of the box**. What you need to do is to reverse every character without changing its shape (glyph/symbol). @Lars answer won't work because a char in Arabic might change based on its position in the word. See here for a similar answer and a solution: [Error while writting Arabic to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780339/write-arabic-to-image-error/25753686#25753686)

Answer (score -1):

in the comments of the manual for [imagettftext](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext), there's an example for RTL languages. [Try this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php#97767)

```
    $wordsArray = explode(" ", $text);

    $rtlCompleteText='';
    for ($i = sizeOf($wordsArray); $i > -1; $i = $i-1) {

        //$lettersArray = explode("|", str_replace(";|", ";", $wordsArray[$i]));
        $lettersArray = explode(";", $wordsArray[$i]);

        $rtlWord='';
        for ($k = sizeOf($lettersArray); $k > -1; $k = $k-1) {
            if (strlen($lettersArray[$k]) > 1) { // make sure its full unicode letter
                $rtlWord = $rtlWord."".$lettersArray[$k].";";
            }
        }

        $rtlCompleteText = $rtlCompleteText." ".$rtlWord;

    }

    return $rtlCompleteText;
}
```

Comment: im talking about imagefttext() and i have tried your example but without any usefulness .<br>

Comment: yes i'm sure , please give me a solution or any links can benefit me .