# Displaying right to left connected languages (like persian and Arabic) in GD - Possible PHP bug

Tags: php, gd

I want to create an image with a text on it with php gd library.

everything is fine, but when I try to write a word from  a right to left connected language (like Persian )  using `imagefttext()`, my text is rendering from left to right (inverse) and the chars are not connected any more .

example of connected chars : **ماه**
example of not connected chars : **م ا ه**

Here is my code :

```
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    $thumb_path = "...";
    $font_path = "..."
    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($thumb_path);
    $color = "...";
    // __month is a Persian word :  ( م ا ه -->  ماه )
    $text = $months." ".__month;
    imagefttext($img,29, 10, 230, 135, $color, $font_path, $text); // <--
    imagejpeg($img);
```

The rendered image :

[image: month]

I know my problem is not encoding.because I already tried this :

```
$text = mb_convert_encoding($text, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

And the result is the same.

there are some library available that maybe can solve this problem. and I know that most of you are not familiar with **Persian** or **Arabic** languages, but my question is why `gd`  does not support right to left connected languages natively ?

could this be a bug in gd library ?

Comment: take a look here https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43899

Comment: Ummmmm,is  this a bug ?

Comment: check http://blog.afsharm.com/2009/04/otrs-gd-library-and-persian-support.html, this person have the same problem, and said that the bug is not going to be resolved, ther are a few link for more information

Comment: Perhaps you should show an exact image of what you expect. It is not clear from the question. And the attached images in the linked bugreport do not work either.

Comment: the text of image should be **ماه**

Comment: @AlirezaFallah this is too small. Could you make a large image of the correctly rendered word and include it in the question?

Comment: Is it the Farsi or Arabic language?

Comment: I cant generate it because of this problem, its farsi , but its the same as arabic in this case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems that nothing helps (setting correct locale), native PHP support is buggy, that's probably why 3rd party package was created:

### Use [php-gd-farsi](https://github.com/IranPhpMaster/php-gd-farsi)

Works as a charm:

[image]

Just copy the library to your PHP directory (don't have to be the admin). The usage is simple:

```
// init:
include('php-gd-farsi-master/FarsiGD.php');
$gd = new FarsiGD();

....
// then convert your text:
$tx = $gd->persianText($str, 'fa', 'normal');
```

You don't even have to set the correct locale! :-)

Whole example code:

```
<?php

include('php-gd-farsi-master/FarsiGD.php');

$gd = new FarsiGD();

// Create a 300x100 image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 100);
$red = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);

// Make the background red
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 299, 99, $red);

// Path to our ttf font file
//$font_file = './Vera.ttf';
$font_file = './cour.ttf';

// Draw the text 'PHP Manual' using font size 13
$text = imagecreatetruecolor(200, 60);
imagefilledrectangle($text, 0, 0, 200, 60, $red);
$str = '**ماه**';
$tx = $gd->persianText($str, 'fa', 'normal');
imagefttext($text, 24, 10, 10, 50, $black, $font_file,$tx );
$im = $text;

// Output image to the browser
header('Content-Type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: nice and complete answer,thank you, it solved my problem, but dont you think this bug should be fixed ?

Comment: @AlirezaFallah yes, definitely should! This package shouldn't be needed!

Comment: Thank you dude, and congrats for being 15k ;)

Comment: Thanks @AlirezaFallah :-) Not yet, still 41 pts missing :-) PS: it is the first time I was typesetting these oriental characters. Cool :-)

Comment: I put this package on Wamp. but can not run it . it returns many 'Undefined variabl' error in FarsiGD.php

Comment: Can you add Arabic support to your accepted answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780339/write-arabic-to-image-error/25753686#25753686

Comment: `(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined offset: -1
in FarsiGD.php (line 81)`

Comment: Text I'm using `'**ماه**'`

Comment: @TMS let me know if we can fix this?

Comment: @AhsanHussain if you have a good working fix that you are sure about yes feel free to update the answer. I have written this 4 years ago and things might have changed since :) I might not be able to validate it though since I am no longer active in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have locale correctly set up?

Looking at the [table of locales](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales), the persian should be probably Farsi - `fa_IR.UTF-8` from the package `fa_utf8`. Don't forget to check if it has been set correctly too:

```
$rv = setlocale(LC_ALL, "fa_IR.UTF-8");
var_dump($rv);
```

**Edit:** tried it and it doesn't seem to help either.