# how modifications in php making SimpleImage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

modifications in php making SimpleImage
I want to make some adjustments on a code
Work code is a compilation of images with text in a single image

```html
  // making SimpleImage instances of selected friends including main image
  $img = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('main.jpg');
  $img1 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('main2.jpg');
  $img2 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('main3.jpg');
  $img3 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('main4.jpg');
  $img4 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('https://graph.facebook.com/1020534352325130/picture');
  $img1->resize(150, 150);
  $img2->resize(150, 150);
  $img3->resize(150, 150);
  $img4->resize(50, 50);
  $img->overlay($img1, 'bottom left', 1, 30, -25);
  $img->overlay($img2, 'bottom', 1, 0, -25);
  $img->overlay($img3, 'bottom right', 1, -30, -25);
  $img->overlay($img4, 'top', 1, 0, 25);
  $img->text('message', 'fb.OTF', 18, '#FFFFFF', 'top', 0, 20);
  $img->save('./dir/' . $_SESSION['gameid2'] . '.jpg');
```

modifications in php making SimpleImage
I want to make line changes the message but added this happened Server Error 500

```html
$img->text('<?php echo $user['name']; ?>', 'fb.OTF', 18, '#FFFFFF', 'top', 0, 20);
```

I also recall the image using a variable as but an error occurred

```html
$img4 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user['id']; ?>/picture');
```

This code works well when it is used so

```html
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user['id']; ?>/picture" />
<?php echo $user['name']; ?>
```

Please help
Good-bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the placement of your `<?php` tags. Instead of this:

```
$img->text('<?php echo $user['name']; ?>', 'fb.OTF', 18, '#FFFFFF', 'top', 0, 20);
```

Try this:

```
<?php
$img->text($user['name'], 'fb.OTF', 18, '#FFFFFF', 'top', 0, 20);
?>
```

And instead of this:

```
$img4 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('https://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user['id']; ?>/picture');
```

Try this:

```
<?php
$img4 = new abeautifulsite\SimpleImage('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $user['id'] . '/picture');
?>
```

Of course, if you're code is already inside a PHP block, you can omit the  `<?php ?>` tags from the example above.

Comment: thax bru
I have another question
How do I make writing coded in this line utf_8

Comment: When you call the Arabic name is not being displayed
thank you very much

Comment: Make sure the font you're using supports Arabic  characters  and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much
I have used the Arabic line but is displayed from left to right
As we know that the Arabic language is working from right to left

Comment: Seems like a GD issue. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21107740/displaying-right-to-left-connected-languages-like-persian-and-arabic-in-gd-p

Comment: Hello my friend
As we know that the `main. jpg` is the background
You could add other backgrounds and each time you download is the background of random selection
Thank you