# drupal: Arabic text on image

Tags: drupal-6, arabic

I would like to display Arabic text on an image on drupal! in the PHP code I use an Arabic font! the text is displayed but with letters parts! do you have any solutions for me! thank you very much

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "with letters parts"? I am not acquainted with arab lettering, so I am sorry if this question seems trivial to you!

Comment: I mean in Arabic, letters are required to be attached to form a word ... the problem I find is that I have my sequence of letters but they are not attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Drupal** has nothing to do here. What you want is to **write Arabic text on/in an image in PHP**.

The simplest and the most standard way is to use PHP's `imagettftext()`. However, `imagettftext()` does not fully support right-to-left languages like Arabic. You need to **correctly** reverse Arabic chars and pass them to `imagettftext()`. See a duplicate : [Error while writting Arabic to image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780339/write-arabic-to-image-error/25753686#25753686)